# List Apache disabled sites

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I use `apache2ctl -S` to list enabled sites:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.xxx.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-www.xxx.org-ssl.conf:1)
Syntax OK
```

Is there a command I can use to list disabled sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is NO, but don't worry. You have an easier way to do so: write

```
a2ensite
```

in the console, and then press `TAB` two times. You'll see a list with all sites.

On the other hand you may use:

```
apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_DUMP_VHOSTS
```

to list your enabled sites, as it eases the output.

Check [apache2ctl doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/httpd.html)